Changing the order of operations in Java produces totally different result for finding prefix sum of an Array
Here is my code solving the problem of Range Sum, problem statement given below :-
class Solution {
    
    public static final int MOD = 1000000007; 

    public int rangeSum(int[] nums, int n, int left, int right) {
        int m = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
        int[] arr = new int[m];

        for(int start = 0, index = 0; start < n; ++start){
            arr[index++] = nums[start];
            for(int i = start + 1; i < n; ++i){
                int lastIndexValInArray = arr[index - 1];
                arr[index++] = (lastIndexValInArray + nums[i]);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        int result = 0;

        for(int i = left - 1; i < right; ++i){
            result += arr[i];
            result%=MOD;
        }

        return result;
    }
}

The above one is giving me correct answer. On the input of new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}
I am getting this prefix sum as the output by the print line statement.
 [1, 3, 6, 10, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 4]

But now if I change the order of the things slightly and directly use arr[index - 1] in calculation, then we will get totally different and incorrect result.
    private int rangeSum(int[] nums, int n, int left, int right) {
        int m = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
        int[] arr = new int[m];

        for(int start = 0, index = 0; start < n; ++start){
            arr[index++] = nums[start];
            for(int i = start + 1; i < n; ++i){
                //int lastArrayIndexVal = ;
                arr[index++] = ( arr[index - 1] + nums[i] ); // directly using arr[index - 1] in the expression
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        int result = 0;

        for(int i = left - 1; i < right; ++i){
            result += arr[i];
            result%=MOD;
        }

        return result;


    }
}

Now if instead of assigning the value arr[index - 1] to an intermediate varaiable, I directly use that in the code, then the prefix sums array has the following values.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4]

Why is this difference in the result ?
The above code is generated in response to solving the challenge on Leetcode, which goes by the name :-
Range Sum of Sorted Subarray Sums
You are given the array nums consisting of n positive integers. You computed the sum of all non-empty continuous subarrays from the array and then sorted them in non-decreasing order, creating a new array of n * (n + 1) / 2 numbers.
Return the sum of the numbers from index left to index right (indexed from 1), inclusive, in the new array. Since the answer can be a huge number return it modulo 10^9 + 7.
Example 1:
Input: nums = [1,2,3,4], n = 4, left = 1, right = 5

Output: 13

Explanation: All subarray sums are 1, 3, 6, 10, 2, 5, 9, 3, 7, 4. After sorting them in non-decreasing order we have the new array [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]. The sum of the numbers from index le = 1 to ri = 5 is 1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 4 = 13.
Constraints:

n == nums.length
1 <= nums.length <= 1000
1 <= nums[i] <= 100
1 <= left <= right <= n * (n + 1) / 2


What is "the problem of Range Sum"?

I have added the problem statement as well. But my main concern is not about the whole problem it's only why assigning an intermediate variable to the computation produces different result. And why using that direct computation producing different result ?

why two different algorithms are given different results....  2nd code: in arr[index++], the ++ is incrementing the index, and arr[index - 1] is using the new incremented value (and by subtracting one so resulting in the value of index before it was incremented) -- Java Language Specification 15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First: "The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated." - = is the assignment operator

It's best to avoid incrementing a variable in one part of an expression and using it in another part. It causes confusion to those who are not fully familiar with the Java language rules.

( suggestion: arr[index] = arr[index - 1] + nums[i]; index += 1; - should be easy understandable even for non-developers )

Please post this in answer format, I will accept it.

So my tacit assumption, that it is the right hand side of the expression, is first going to be evaluated, and that value will be saved in memory location pointed by the variable on the left hand side, is wrong.

Yes.  Your tacit assumption was incorrect.

@Stephen C please post the full detailed answer, I mean, I would really value that detailed answer, to the benefit of others who my be facing similar such situation.

Frankly ... people in the same situation as yours would be unlikely to find this Q&A.
